# Segmentation fault while finding middle element in a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to find the middle element of a linked List, but I'm getting a segmentation fault, and I'm not sure what is going wrong. This is my implementation of the hare rabbit algorithm:

```
//fast slow pointer method  
void ptMiddle(struct node **head_ref)
{   
    struct node *fast = (*head_ref);
    struct node *slow = (*head_ref);
    fast = fast->next;

    while(fast!=NULL)
    {   
        // printf("%d%d",slow->data,fast->data);
        slow = slow->next;
        fast = fast->next->next;
    }
    printf("Middle elemnet is:%d\n",slow->data);
}

int main()
{
    struct node * head=NULL;
    push(&head,1);
    push(&head,2);
    push(&head,3);
    push(&head,4);
    printList(&head);
    printf("M:%d\n",middleNode(&head)->data);
    printf("here");
    append(&head,5);
    append(&head,6);
    printList(&head);
    printf("M:%d\n",middleNode(&head)->data);
    printf("here");
    ptMiddle(&head);

    return 0;  
}
```

Please help out.

Comment: The implementation of `push` is missing

Comment: `fast->next->next;` will fail if `fast->next` is `NULL`.

Comment: provide [mcve].

Comment: @Yunnosch Apologizem, I can see it was me error https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44166072/revisions. ramit pahwa should try to fix this. Thanks

Comment: In the future, you’ll save yourself a lot of trouble if you run the program in the debugger and see which line crashes the program.  Another good technique is to add `assert()` statements that the operations you’re doing are really valid. Here, that might include `assert(head_ref);` and `assert(slow);`.

Comment: @xsami I had temporarily a comment here, to add information (fast) which I also edited into the question (I had to wait for peer review). It was meant to be in a matter-of-fact way, but had to reason the "small" edit thoroughly to make sure it got accepted. No need to apologize for a little accident - that was not what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the line:

```
fast = fast->next->next;
```

Imagine you have two elements in the linked list: `A -> B -> NULL`, first you start by executing `fast = fast->next`, which results in fast pointing to `B` node.

When you enter the while loop, you try to get `B->next->next`, which results in `NULL->next`, which clearly doesn't exist.

The implementation is plain wrong, you should make sure to avoid this case. The while could be changed to:

```
while(fast!=NULL && fast->next != NULL)
```

and this would fix it.

Keep in mind that in case of a pair number of elements, you'll always get the middle one which is more left. So in `A -> B -> NULL` you'd get node `A`.

Comment: Thanks,I understood the issue here